# dynamically allocated struct array for open hash table

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am trying to implement a simple open hash in c++ for the sake of learning. I am getting very confused about the interaction of functions with array pointers, and I am at the end of my wits.

The code:

```
struct node{
    int data;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
    bool state;
    node(){
        prev = next = NULL;
        state = true;
    }
};

//state true means empty, state false  means full.
void insert(node *array,int value){
    node *current = array;
    if(array->state == true){
        array->data = value;
        array->state = false;
    } else {
        node* add = new node();
        add->data = value;
        add->state = false;
        while(current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next =  add;
        add->prev = current;
        
    }
}

void display(node *array, int size){
    node *show = new node();
    for(int i = 0; i< size; i++){
        if(array->state == false){
            cout<<array->data;
            show = array;
            while(show->next != NULL){
                show = show->next;
                cout<<" --> "<<show->data;
            }
            
        } else {
            cout<<"Empty.";
        }
        cout<<"\n\n";
    }
}
int main(){
    int size;
    cout<<"Enter size of the hash table: ";
    cin>>size;
    node *array = new node[size];
    int value;
    cout<<"Enter Value: ";
    cin>>value;
    int index = value%size;
    //inserting single value
    insert(&array[index],value);
    //Hash table output.
    display(array,size);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, instead of showing "empty" in places where the array's state is empty, it seems as if the entire array has the same value. The problem lies in the insert function, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Your `display` function only checks the very first `node` in the array. You need to actually iterate over all nodes (e.g.: `array[i].state` instead of `array->state`)

Comment: `node *show = new node();` -- Your `display` function should not be allocating a new node.  It makes no sense to create a node just for display purposes.  Your function should just display the existing data that you created.  In addition, your code leaks memory in multiple places -- when you use `new`, you're responsible for issuing calls to `delete` -- you simply can't write proper data structures in C++ without addressing all aspects of memory management, including deallocating the memory.

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks for your answer. I am pretty embarrassed that I did not see this simple mistake. The code works now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , Thank you for that information. I will fix the memory leaks. I am still new to memory management and pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this by making the Hashtable an array of pointers to Node. A `nullptr` then means the slot is empty and you don't have empty and full nodes. Also Nodes only need a next pointer and usually new entries are added to the beginning of the buckets instead of the end (allows duplicate entries to "replace" older ones). Inserting at the beginning of a list becomes real easy with `Node **`.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct Table {
    struct Node {
        Node * next;
        int data;
        Node(Node **prev, int data_) : next{*prev}, data{data_} {
            *prev = this;
        }
    };

    std::size_t size;
    Node **tbl;
    Table(std::size_t size_) : size{size_}, tbl{new Node*[size]} { }
    ~Table() {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            Node *p = tbl[i];
            while(p) {
                Node *t = p->next;
                delete p;
                p = t;
            }
        }
        delete[] tbl;
    }
    void insert(int value) {
        Node **slot = &tbl[value % size];
        new Node(slot, value);
    }
    void display() const {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            std::cout << "Slot " << i << ":";
            for (const Node *node = tbl[i]; node; node = node->next) {
                std::cout << " " << node->data;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    std::size_t size;
    std::cout << "Enter size of the hash table: ";
    std::cin >> size;
    Table table{size};
    int value;
    std::cout << "Enter Value: ";
    std::cin >> value;
    //inserting single value
    table.insert(value);
    //Hash table output.
    table.display();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This took me a good while to understand, but it was quite helpful. Why did you add the keyword 'const' in 'void display() const' ?

Comment: Because displaying the table does not change the table. You should make everything const by default and only remove const when modifying things is actually what you intend to do. Frequently you want the same code with and without const.